# TodoList using useState and React - Problem updating the todoList

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem updating my todoList using React and useState... Should I try using "push" or something different to update my list ?

thank you very much !!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  // State search et sa fonction de modification
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const updateSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    console.log(search);
  };
  // State de liste et sa fonction de modification
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const updateList = () => {
    setList([...list, search]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome on your todolist</h1>
      <br />
      <input type="text" onChange={updateSearch} value={search} />
      <button onClick={updateList}>enter</button>
      <ul></ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Please clarify exactly what the problem is.  "I have a problem" is pretty vague.

Comment: You're doing it right, by using the spread you're creating a copy of the current list  with the search result, push will mutate the original array, in react is not a good practice to mutate the array cause it can lead to unexpected behaviors, so short story spread operator is perfect for your example.

Comment: Hello Guys !! Thank you very much for your reply ! this is my first post on Stack : )

Comment: My problem is that when pressing enter the first array is always empty ... @jm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because useState is asynchronous, if you want to log the state after updating it you can use useEffect hook with `list` as a dependency

Also I would like recommend adding a key to each element of your list, a quick way to do it is to use the array index, like this:

```
 {list.map((item,index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        ))}
```

But it will be better to have your list as a list of object `[value,id]` and generate an uuid() when you add items to your list

Answer (score 0):

I will rephrase my question : 
I worked on my code again and everything seems to work but when I console log the array list, the array first array is always empty...

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  // State search et sa fonction de modification
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const updateSearch = (e) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
    console.log(search);
  };
  // State de liste et sa fonction de modification
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);
  const updateList = () => {
    setList([...list, search]);
    setSearch("");
    console.log(list);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome on your todolist</h1>
      <br />
      <input type="text" onChange={updateSearch} value={search} />
      <button onClick={updateList}>enter</button>
      <h1>what is inside of list : {list}</h1>

      <ul>
        {list.map((item) => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```